# Updating Alternative text of a button

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code as part of a Job site labor form, which links a full labor call on the "LocLabor" sheet to various single day sign in sheets.  This particular code is to add a complete day to the form, and works great, with the exception of these two lines at the bottom:

```
 .Buttons(bnum).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = dayint + 1
 .Buttons(bnum + 1).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = dayint + 1
```

The "scopy", "ecopy", and "brow" variables are used to work out the appropriate lines to copy and paste to the next day. The buttons that are being altered are the newly pasted buttons that were copied within the scopy/ecopy range and are used to add or delete a line from the table they refer to.  I need to be able to change the AltText because I am using that as a reference for which day of the labor call they apply to. The "numdays" variable pulls from locsht.Range("L3").Value, which is set to the current number of days on the form prior to running the macro.  So it would have a value of 2 when I see the error

Now to the issue - if I have two days existing in the document and I execute the below code, the name of the button changes, but the Alternative Text does not (it remains as "2" or whatever it was prior to copying).  Days 4 and up work perfectly though, it is just the transition from day 2 to 3 that I cannot get to work! It also works if I switch out "dayint + 1" to a string, like "banana" for example, but that obviously doesn't help me.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub add_day()
Dim numdays As String
Dim tbl As TableStyle
Dim newsht As Worksheet
Dim locsht As Worksheet
Dim scopy As Integer
Dim ecopy As Integer
Dim brow As Integer
Dim dayint As Integer
Dim bnum As Integer
Dim tblstart As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'unlock sheet
Worksheets("LocLabor").Unprotect Password:=SuperSecretPW

'set/get variables
Set locsht = Worksheets("LocLabor")
numdays = locsht.Range("L3").Value
dayint = numdays
Worksheets("Labor Sign In Day " & numdays).Copy Before:=Sheets(numdays + 4)
Worksheets("Labor Sign In Day " & numdays & " (2)").Name = "Labor Sign In Day " & numdays + 1

'update number of days on sheet
locsht.Range("L3") = locsht.Range("L3").Value + 1

'rename new sign in sheet
Set newsht = Worksheets("Labor Sign In Day " & numdays + 1)
newsht.Unprotect Password:=SuperSecretPW

'figure out which rows to copy on main sheet
scopy = locsht.ListObjects(dayint).Range.Rows(1).Row - 1
brow = locsht.ListObjects(dayint).Range.Rows.Count
ecopy = scopy + brow


'Copy/paste new day on LocLabor
locsht.Activate
locsht.Rows(scopy & ":" & ecopy).Copy
locsht.Rows(ecopy + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
locsht.ListObjects("Tableday" & numdays).Resize Range("A" & scopy + 1 & ":" & "H" & ecopy)
locsht.Range("A" & ecopy + 2 & ":" & "H" & ecopy + 2) = "=IFERROR($A$17+" & numdays & "," & """Enter Load in Date at Top"")"
locsht.Rows(ecopy + 1).EntireRow.Delete
locsht.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$H$" & ecopy + (ecopy - scopy + 1)
locsht.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=locsht.Rows(ecopy + 1)
locsht.ListObjects(dayint + 1).Name = "Tableday" & numdays + 1

bnum = (dayint * 2) + 3

tblstart = locsht.ListObjects(dayint + 1).Range.Rows(1).Row + 1

'Enter correct formulas into sign in sheet
With newsht
.ListObjects(1).Name = "signinday" & numdays + 1
.Range("i12") = Left(newsht.Range("i12").Formula, 28) & numdays & Right(newsht.Range("i12").Formula, 48)
.Range("A17") = "=IF(ISBLANK(LocLabor!G" & tblstart & ")=FALSE,LocLabor!G" & tblstart & "&"" ""&LocLabor!F" _
& tblstart & ",IF(ISBLANK(LocLabor!D" & tblstart & ")=TRUE," & """""" & ",LocLabor!D" & tblstart & "))"
.Range("B17") = "=IF(ISBLANK(LocLabor!B" & tblstart & ")=TRUE, """", LocLabor!B" & tblstart & ")"
.Range("G17") = "=IF(ISBLANK(LocLabor!C" & tblstart & ")=TRUE, """", LocLabor!C" & tblstart & ")"
End With


'rename pasted buttons, update alttext
With locsht
 .Buttons(bnum).Name = "Button " & bnum
 .Buttons(bnum + 1).Name = "Button " & bnum + 1
 .Buttons(bnum).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = dayint + 1
 .Buttons(bnum + 1).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = dayint + 1
 End With


'lock down sheets
Worksheets("LocLabor").Protect Password:=SuperSecretPW, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True
Worksheets("LocLabor").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

Worksheets("Labor Sign In Day " & numdays + 1).Protect Password:=SuperSecretPW, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True
Worksheets("Labor Sign In Day " & numdays + 1).EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(3, 0).Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: UPDATE:  There seems to be something about the number 3 that it doesn't like.  If I change this line `.Buttons(bnum + 1).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = dayint + 1` to `.Buttons(bnum + 1).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = "4"` it works perfectly.  However the following does not work at all: `.Buttons(bnum + 1).ShapeRange.AlternativeText = "3"`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No errors.  It just doesn't change.  I managed to work out that if I change it to something other than 2, and THEN change it to 3 (by way of dayint +1) it works.  No idea why the transition from 2 to 3 specifically would be a problem though.

Comment: If there's no error when setting the value then I'd guess there's something elsewhere in your code which means you're not working with the button you think you are....  Have you tried reducing this to a smaller standalone example?  There too much else going on there for anyone to be able to test your code.  In my simple testing, there's absolutely no problem with changing alternative text from "2" to "3"

Comment: I thought that at first too, but if that were the case then it wouldn't work for any value.  As it stands, I can manipulate the alternative text on both of those buttons to anything except 3.

Comment: There must have just been some error with those particular buttons.  I had previously ruled that out, assuming there was some math wrong somewhere in my code, since there was no problem elsewhere, but after deleting and starting with newly inserted buttons, everything works as it should.  I did also go back to a previously saved file and sure enough, with those particular buttons it would absolutely not change from "2" to "3" without changing to something else first. Weird. And thank you for your input as always Tim!